# In Spring MVC 3, how do I bind an object to a query string when the query string parameters don't match up with the object fields?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-binding

A 3rd party is sending me part of the data to fill in my domain object via a query string. I need to partially fill in my domain object, and then have the user fill in the rest via a form. I don't have any control over the query string parameters coming in, so I can't change those, but I'd really like to be able to use Spring MVC's data binding abilities, rather than doing it by hand.

How can I do this?

To add some complication to this, some of the parameters will require extensive processing because they map to other objects (such as mapping to a user from just a name) that may not even exist yet and will need to be created. This aspect, I assume, can be handled using property editors. If I run into trouble with this, I will ask another question.

Once I have a partially filled domain object, passing it on to the edit view, etc. is no problem, but I don't know how to properly deal with the initial domain object population.

Comment: Start here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebRequestDataBinder.html

Comment: This might be helpful: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I have been able to come up with so far is to have an extra class that has it's properties named to match the inbound query parameters and a function to convert from this intermediary class to my domain class.

This seems like a lot of overhead though just to map between variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just have the getter named differently from the setter, or have 2 getters and 2 setters if necessary?

```
private int spn;

// Standard getter/setter    

public int getSpn() {
    return spn;
}

public void setSpn(int spn) {
    this.spn = spn;
}


// More descriptively named getter/setter

public int getShortParameterName() {
    return spn;
}

public void setShortParameterName(int spn) {
    this.spn = spn;
}
```

Maybe that is not standard bean convention, but surely would work?